# I'm struggling with some if statements - Python 2.7.9 (big noob)

Tags: python, if-statement

I am wanting to make a portion of a game where you have a gun with only one bullet. But you have two chances to use it. so if you used it the first time u couldn't use it the second time, or vice versa.

```
ammo_amount = 1

ammo = raw_input ("Shoot?")
if ammo == 'y':
    print ("you shot")
    ammo_amount-1

else:
    print("You didn't shoot")

ammo_2 = raw_input ("do you want to shoot again?")

if ammo_2 == 'y':
    if ammo_amount == '1':
        print ("you can shoot again")

    if ammo_amount == '0':
        print ("you can't shoot again")
if ammo_2 == 'n':
    print ("You didn't shoot")
```

Comment: Small Suggestion: If you are learning python, better start from the official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). You might take 5 days maximum to finish it, but it will really help you in learning as to why these kind of errors are caused. All the best. May the gods of Python be with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings with an integer:

```
ammo_amount = 1

# ...

if ammo_amount == '1':

# 

if ammo_amount == '0':
```

These tests will never be true, strings are never equal to integers even if they contain characters that can be interpreted as the same number when reading the text; compare with another number instead:

```
if ammo_amount == 1:
```

and

```
if ammo_amount == 0:
```

You also never altered `ammo_amount`; the following expression produces a new number:

```
ammo_amount-1
```

but you are ignoring that new number. Store it back in the `ammo_amount` variable:

```
ammo_amount = ammo_amount - 1
```

Comment: So don't use number one? (i'm really new to python XP)

Comment: @BhargavRao: two different but related problems.

Comment: @MoJoe: where do I say that? I gave you better alternatives; compare against actual numbers.

Comment: I am seriously confused, it basically skips the second part of the code...??

Comment: @MoJoe: I gave you replacement code for 3 specific lines. I'm not sure why you think this skips any part of your code?

Comment: nevermind, i understand now, i wasnt using intergers... stupid me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To explain what Martijn talked about in his answer about comparing strings and integers,

The way that we handle data in computing varies depending on the *type* of a variable. This type determines what operations you can and can't do with a variable. You can find the type of a variable by calling the `type()` function:

```
type( 5 )     # <type 'int'>
type( '5' )   # <type 'str'>
type( 5.0 )   # <type 'float'>
num = 5
type( num )   # <type 'int'>
```

See how `5`, `'5'`, and `5.0` all have different types? We can do different things with these different literals. For example, we can get the length of `'5'` because it's a string, which is a sequence, but we can't get the length of `5`.

```
len( '5' )    # 1
len( 5 )      # TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

When you compare two objects of incompatible types, the interpreter won't always do what you expect. Consider this code below:

```
num = 5
num == 5      # True
num == '5'    # False, comparing int to str
```

Why is the second comparison false? Well the interpreter doesn't know what we want to do. The way `==` comparison is implemented for strings and integers does not compare the integer value of the string because a string could contain non-integer data. As far as the interpreter knows, we might try to do something like this:

```
num == 'clearly not a number'
```

As Martijn said, your issue is that you're trying to compare an integer (`ammo_amount`) to a string (`'1'` or `'0'`).

Hope this sheds some more light on your mistake!